# chromedriver using selenium for scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to load chrome web driver using selenium in command but getting an error

1)I have updated my chrome browser and webdriver to the latest version
2)checked by using the same version of chrome browser and driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/prasun.j/Desktop/chromedriver')
```

I expect to pop up a browser window but getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\prasun.j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to write automation extension zip
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Comment: What is the browser version? it must be 73 to use this chromedriver.

Comment: @dpap My comment is still valid. You don't have to explicitly write the `.exe` extension.

Comment: @Guy I also tried using 72 version of browser and driver both but still got the same error

Comment: @PrasunJain You need browser version 73 for this driver, not 72. For Chrome version 72 use ChromeDriver 2.46.

Comment: I m telling you previously I tried with 72 version of both browser and driver but still got same error, somebody told me use latest version of both so i tried

Comment: @dpap I m also using the same version of both as yours but still not working

Comment: fyi: if you're working in winderp you'll probably have to replace the slashes in your file path with double backslashes to get it to work.

Comment: @PrasunJain you still have the problem?

Comment: @dpap sorry friend missed your comment, no I m not facing problem anymore thanks to you guys

Comment: @Prasun Jain if you think that my answer helped you to solve your issue, you can mark it as correct :). Thank you,bye.

Answer (score 3):

Notes:

- Be sure that you have already installed the selenium package
- Download chromedriver.exe from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=73.0.3683.20/) (newest version - 73+) and insert it in your code (be sure that is unzipped).
- Also, replace "/" with "\\".
- Install the proper Chrome driver (73+) so to be combined with chromedriver version (73+ too)
- Check the answer below ...

This is from the the official Chrome Driver website:

[image]

Proper usage:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\User\\prasun.j\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe')

# or as @MosheSlavin answered 

driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\prasun.j\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still getting same error

Comment: @dpap selenium is installed

Comment: @dpap i have referred to official websites suggestion but still not resolved

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64),getting this error with chrome 73@dpap

Comment: I don't have driver for linux in my computer @dpap